# DAX Dynamic Total with Power View

Tags: powerpivot, dax, powerview

I am attempting to graph, via Power View, the sum of all account balances at various points in time, so that I can see how the total is changing.

I do not have transaction history (add / subtract), only 'Balance' at a specific point in time for each account.

A simplified example of my data is:

> `Account  Date              Balance`
>   `a111     01 January 2015   100`
>   `a111     01 February 2015  150`
>   `b222     01 March 2015     200`
>   `c333     01 March 2015     300`
>   `b222     01 May 2015       150`
>   `d444     01 June 2015      400`

As far as I can tell, I need to create a measure to generate a dynamic rank per 'Account', ordered by latest date.  I should then be able to create a second measure to SUM each account where the rank = 1.

There is a similar example of this issue discussed in the question  [PowerPivot DAX - Dynamic Ranking Per Group (Min Per Group)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742186/powerpivot-dax-dynamic-ranking-per-group-min-per-group), however I cannot seem to get this to display how I want on a line graph in Power View.

What I want to display on the line graph is (letting the graph sort out the missing dates):

> `Date         Balance`
>   `01 Jan 2015   100           -- Account a111 only`
>   `01 Feb 2015   150           -- Account a111 only, but the new value`
>   `01 Mar 2015   650           -- Accounts a111 (latest), b222 and c333`
>   `01 May 2015   600           -- As above, but account b222 is updated`
>   `01 Jun 2015  1000           -- Latest values for all accounts`

However, what I am currently seeing is:

> `Date         Balance`
>   `01 Jan 2015   100          -- Sum of Balances matching this date`
>   `01 Feb 2015   150          -- As above`
>   `01 Mar 2015   500          -- As above`
>   `01 May 2015   150          -- As above`
>   `01 Jun 2015   400          -- As above`

The problem, as far as I can tell, is that at each data point in the graph, the 'filter context' is reducing down to only the rows that match the date, whereas I need all rows on on before that date with a 'rank' of 1.

For reference, I am using Excel 2013 and the data is ultimately coming in via Power Query (pulling data from SharePoint), so I can work some magic there if necessary (i.e. generating a numeric 'group id' for use with DAX MAX() function, as that doesn't seem to like strings).

I hope this is not to confusing, and thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is to have a separate date dimension table so balance can be independently calculated on a per-month basis without respect to the fact table.

Let's assume you have a date table called Date.

So, first create the base measure

```
[Total Balance] := SUM( FactTable[Balance] )
```

Next we calculate the first month in the fact table to use as a floor for looking through our Date table values.

```
[First Ever Balance Date] := FIRSTDATE( ALL( FactTable[Date] ) )
```

And now we determine the last date with a balance for the date range between that first month and the current month in context:

```
[Last Balance Date] :=
LASTNONBLANK (
    DATESBETWEEN ( Date[Date], [First Ever Balance Date], MAX ( Date[Month] ) ),
    [Total Balance]
)
```

So take account *a111* in the month of *5/1/2015*. This measure will look in all the dates between *1/1/2015* (our `[First Ever Balance Date]` ) and *5/1/2015* ( the `MAX Date[Month]` ) , find the last row with a balance and return the corresponding `Date[Date]` ( *2/1/2015* ).

This measure will return BLANK for any month before an account's initial balance. Using BLANKS in date filtering doesn't work, so we should replace these BLANK values with the [First Ever Balance Date] to ensure the running balance for that account will still return 0.

```
[Last Balance Date Remove Blanks] :=
IF (
    ISBLANK ( [Last Balance Date] ),
    [First Ever Balance Date],
    [Last Balance Date]
)
```

Now we can calculate the current balance of any account for any month by looking up the balance as of the `Last Balance Date Remove Blanks`

```
[Last Balance] :=
CALCULATE (
    [Total Balance],
    DATESBETWEEN ( Date[Date], [Last Balance Date Remove Blanks], 
    [Last Balance Date Remove Blanks] )
)
```

And finally we use a SUMX across the accounts to add up their individual `Last Balance` amounts.

```
[Account Total Balance] := SUMX( ALL( FactTable[Account] ), [Last Balance] )
```

Now in your pivot table you just put Date[Month] on the rows and [Account Total Balance] as the measure. Note this will include months with no fact table rows like 4/1/2015 in your sample set. If you wish to exclude these, add another intermediate measure to count your fact table rows:

```
[Fact Table Row Count] := COUNTROWS ( FactTable )
```

And then create a measure to return BLANK() if [Fact Table Row Count] is BLANK(), and otherwise [Account Total Balance]

```
[Account Balance Hide Rows] :=
IF (
    ISBLANK ( [Fact Table Row Count] ),
    BLANK (),
    [Account Balance]
)
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle, having been a bit tied up I haven't been able to try this as yet, but I appreciate your detailed response.